# How to DRY up associations in includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

I have a `scope` method in which i'm using `includes` to eager load all the necessary associations. But i'm not sure how to DRY up the associations used in the `includes`?

Here is the `scope` defined in the model:

```
scope :with_associates, (lambda do
    includes(user: :contact,
             appointments: [:customer, templates: :page],
             bundles: appointments: [:customer, templates: :page]])
  end)
```

How to DRY up this scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Never tried to make that DRY. Anyway, I'll try.

```
def appointments_for_includes
  Hash[appointments: [:customer, templates: :page]]
end

def associations_for_includes
  Hash[user: :contact, bundles: appointments_for_includes].merge(appointments_for_includes)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in DRYing that - you'll make it less clear. For the sake of the repetition of `appointments: [:customer, templates: :page]`, the cost of DRYing this is outweighed by the clarity of the original

Comment: Yes but in case if i want to use `appointments: [:customer, templates: :page]` for some other scopes then it would be necessary to dry it up.

Comment: Yes - that's true - but not given in your example.